# What is the difference between git stash save and git stash store?

Tags: git, git-stash

Looking for an explanation based on their different use cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although their colloquial meaning is quite similar (to save ≈ to store), in git they're two completely unrelated sub-commands of the `stash` command. This is not really a comparison, but in short here's what they are :

`stash save` creates a stash entry, but is deprecated. There are no real use-cases not covered by `stash push`, which is implied when no other sub-command is given, so most people just do `git stash` to create a entry

`stash store` is a plumbing command to explicitly put a stash entry in the reflog (which is automatically done behind the scenes anyway, this is the way to explicitly fire it in a scripting context)